# How to conditionally display export file window in Blender?

Tags: python, blender

Can someone give me an idea of how can I export a file from Blender only if a certain condition is met?

Here is the code example

```
class OBJECT_OT_export_model(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    bl_idname = 'flex.export'
    bl_label = "Export"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        isValid = validate() #custom function for model validation
        if(isValid):
            #show export dialog

            
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

However, the export file window is displayed every time.